# Ruby on Rails and Netezza backend

Tags: ruby-on-rails, netezza

Anyone know of how they would go about pulling data from a Netezza backend in ruby on rails.

Any resources would help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would strongly consider using [JRuby](http://www.jruby.org/) and then use the JDBC drivers for Neteeza.  For more information on using JDBC and JRuby with rails, check out https://github.com/nicksieger/activerecord-jdbc-adapter

Answer (score 1):

I have an enterprise Ruby on Rails 3 web application, hosted on Windows Server 2008, which connects to SQL Server via ActiveRecord and Netezza via DBI.  I tested connecting to Netezza in various ways:

- Ruby + ODBC based DBI **can** connect to Netezza
- Ruby + AR **cannot** connect to Netezza.
- Ruby + AR-based ODBC (activerecord-odbc-adapter) **does not** support Netezza.
- JRuby + Java-based JDBC **can** connect to Netezza.
- JRuby + AR-based JDBC **cannot** connect to Netezza.
- IronRuby + ODBC can **probably** connect to Netezza.

Answer (score 1):

We tinkered with this a little while back and settled on JRuby + JDBC + custom AR adapter gem. It's rough, but I made the [activerecord-netezza-adapter](https://github.com/robbkidd/activerecord-netezza-adapter) gem and it's working so far.

(Hola, Kirby!)